# Access SQL Query Help Using Not Exists

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a table named sys_event_log with the following columns:

user_name,
event_type,
event_message,
time_stamp

Login and logout events are tracked with event_type of either "Login Success" or "Logout Event"

Using SQL in Access I'm trying to return a list of distinct users that have logged into the database that have not yet logged out based **strictly** on the event log event_types and time_stamps.

The query I have come up with so far is:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
     a.user_name,
     a.event_type,
     a.time_stamp
FROM
     sys_event_log a
WHERE NOT EXISTS
 (
     SELECT
          1
     FROM
          sys_event_log b
     WHERE
          b.time_stamp > a.time_stamp 
          AND a.user_name = b.user_name 
          AND a.event_type = "Logout Event"
 )
AND a.event_type = "Login Success";
```

It feels close but it is not returning the expected dataset.

Comment: Would this work correctly if you allow multiple simultaneous connections of the same user?

Comment: @ypercube does it matter? If that happens, there are 2 outcomes (1) the last entry is a Logout => user is not listed (2) there are multiple logins after the last Logout => user is listed multiple times **once for each login**

Comment: So, if we have in the event_log: login, login, login, logout , then the user is not listed while he still has 2 active logins. Correct?

Comment: to answer the question. yes.  it is possible to open the application multiple times... but they would have to make multiple copies of it from their shared directory to do so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  SELECT a.user_name
       , COUNT(*) AS logins
       , ( SELECT COUNT( b.time_stamp ) 
             FROM sys_event_log b 
             WHERE b.user_name = a.user_name
               AND b.event_type = "Logout Event"
          ) AS logouts
       , logins - logouts AS activeConnections
    FROM sys_event_log a
    WHERE a.event_type = "Login Success"
    GROUP BY a.user_name
    HAVING logins > logouts
```

Comment: i will deffinately be saving this query. the question of multiple simultaneous connections has never been a major issue.  for the most part the users wouldn't know how to achieve something like that, nor would they want to, but i can see now that it could cause problems.

Comment: since the ultimate goal is to be able to determine if/who is actively connected to the application at times where everyone needs to be disconnected (say i need to do a database update and we cant figgure out which of the 25 users is still connected, and it turns out he left his computer on when he went on vacation, true story) By doing a simple alteration (having activeconnections > 0) i believe that this should work.

Answer (score 1):

It will make more sense if you use

```
b.event_type = "Logout Event"
```

here

```
      b.time_stamp > a.time_stamp 
      AND a.user_name = b.user_name 
      AND a.event_type = "Logout Event"
```

Comment: glaring errors are always the worst... i guess i just needed someone else to look at it! thanks (won't let me accept as the answer for 8 minutes)

Comment: @cyberwiki: I think the above query has one more flaw. It doesn't work well when a user can make many (simultaneous) connections.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT 
   a.user_name, 
   a.event_type, 
   a.time_stamp
FROM
   sys_event_log a
WHERE a.event_type = "Login Success" AND
   a.time_stamp = ( SELECT MAX( b.time_stamp ) 
                    FROM sys_event_log b 
                    WHERE b.user_name = a.user_name )
```

Comment: i believe that would do it as well.  I'll have to test it, but the logic looks solid.

Comment: Yours is bit more efficient by having the condition b.time_stamp > a.timestamp in the subquery. My version can be improved by adding b.time_stamp >= a.time_stamp to condition in the subquery.

Comment: See comment against question - this changes the meaning of the query as commented, and it will not work once you have other event_types involved beyond login/logout.